# Prevent Leaflet from requesting non-existing tiles (Error 404)

Tags: leaflet, bounds

I need to add bounds to a tile layer, so leaflet doesn't make requests about tiles that don't exist.
[image]

In this example there are two layers. One based with Google Maps and the second with the NDVI polygon. When loading the polygon, try to bring tiles by completing the full size of the base map.
Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer-bounds (2) Why are the 404s a problem?

Comment: Hi Ivan. 404 is a problem because i have to pay every API GET.